# I just wanted to scrape some data from https://www.naukrigulf.com/ but it gave me None value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests as r

src = r.get('https://www.naukrigulf.com/construction-jobs?industryType=10&locale=en').content
soup=bs(src,'lxml')

first_item = soup.find('div',{'class':'srp-listing'})

print(first_item)
```

if it gave you None value please tell me

Comment: Does that website use javascript to create page content?  The `requests` module cannot process javascript.

Comment: how could I know if it uses java script and if it uses javascript how could I scrape data

Answer (score 1):

```
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

url = 'https://www.naukrigulf.com/spapi/jobapi/search?ClusterInd=10&Experience=&Keywords=construction&KeywordsAr=&Limit=30&Location=&LocationAr=&Offset=30&SortPreference=relevance&breadcrumb=1&clusterSelected=1&geoIpCityName=Tokyo&geoIpCountryName=Japan&locationId=87&nationality=&nationalityLabel=&pageNo=2&seo=1&showBellyFilters=true&srchId='

headers = {
    'appId' : '205',
    'systemId': '1112'
}

r = scraper.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

The page loads data from external URL, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can use this snippet to load data to pandas DataFrame:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_url = "https://www.naukrigulf.com/spapi/jobapi/search"

params = {
    "ClusterInd": "10",
    "Keywords": "construction",
    "Limit": "30",
    "Offset": "0",
}

headers = {"appId": "205", "clientId": "desktop", "systemId": "1112"}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()

df = pd.DataFrame([j["Job"] for j in data["Jobs"]])
print(df.head(5).to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Designation | Location | jobInfo | Experience | Company | JobId | JdURL | LatestPostedDate | Vacancies | IsTopEmployer | IsFeaturedEmployer | IsPremium | IsWebJob | IsQuickWebJob | LogoUrl | TELogoUrl | IsApplied | IsTopEmployerLite | Whitelistedkeywords | keywords | Email | IsFormBasedApply | jobRedirection | shortlisted | expiringSoon | isArchived | recruiterActive | isRecruiterActive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Construction Manager | Saudi Arabia - Saudi Arabia | We are hiring for the position of Construction Manager Project Location: Dammam Remarks: Aramco project experience preferred | {'Min': '20', 'Max': '25'} | {'Name': 'China Railway Construction Corporation Limited Sa', 'Id': '205049'} | 190722000045 | https://www.naukrigulf.com/construction-manager-jobs-in-saudi-arabia-in-china-railway-construction-corporation-limited-sa-20-to-25-years-n-cd-205049-jid-190722000045 | 1658213448 | 1 | false | false | false | false | false |  |  | false | false | construction manager,construction,civil,construction management,civil construction | Construction Manager, Construction, Civil, Construction Management, Civil Construction |  | false | false | False | False | False | True | True |
| Design and Construction Interface/Engineering Manager | Saudi Arabia - Saudi Arabia | Project Location: Dammam Remarks: Aramco project experience preferred | {'Min': '15', 'Max': '20'} | {'Name': 'China Railway Construction Corporation Limited Sa', 'Id': '205049'} | 190722000083 | https://www.naukrigulf.com/engineering-manager-jobs-in-saudi-arabia-in-china-railway-construction-corporation-limited-sa-15-to-20-years-n-cd-205049-jid-190722000083 | 1658216985 | 1 | false | false | false | false | false |  |  | false | false | design,engineering manager,design engineering,engineering management,engineering | Design, Construction Interface, Engineering Manager, Design Engineering, Design Construction, Construction Interface, Engineering Management, Engineering |  | false | false | False | False | False | True | True |
| General Manager/Construction Manager(Arabic Speaker) | Abu Dhabi - United Arab Emirates | Drive and spearhead change management, when required to develop cost estimates for the performance of extra work and changed conditions;Prepare trade contracts and bid packages in conjunction with the Procurement and Contract Section, when required, as well as provide feedback for evaluation purposes;Must be Native Arabic Speaker | {'Min': '15', 'Max': '25'} | {'Name': 'Confidential Company', 'Id': '200495'} | 210722000035 | https://www.naukrigulf.com/general-manager-constructio-jobs-in-abu-dhabi-uae-in-confidential-15-to-25-years-n-cd-200495-jid-210722000035 | 1658390954 | 1 | false | false | false | false | false |  |  | false | false | construction management,project manager,civil construction,project management,infrastructure | construction management, project manager, Civil Construction, Project Management, Infrastructure |  | false | false | False | False | False | True | True |
| Construction Manager | Dubai - United Arab Emirates | -At least 15 years of experience in construction project management and from the Main Contractor background;Negotiate contracts with vendors and present formal documentation for approval when required Ensure that contracts are fit for purpose, cost-effective and incorporate appropriate Service Level Agreements Provide overall site management, coordination, planning, specification of business proposals and coordination of subcontractors Study job specifications to determine appropriate co... | {'Min': '10', 'Max': '15'} | {'Name': 'Confidential Company', 'Id': '89635'} | 200722000081 | https://www.naukrigulf.com/construction-manager-jobs-in-dubai-uae-in-confidential-10-to-15-years-n-cd-89635-jid-200722000081 | 1658311596 | 1 | false | false | false | false | false |  |  | false | false | construction management,construction,project,civil,site | Construction Management, Construction, Project, Civil, Site |  | false | false | False | False | False | True | True |
| QC Manager With Underpass Construction Project Experience | Al Madina Al Munawarah , Riyadh , Jubail - Saudi Arabia | Experience in underground tunnel construction is preferred;Minimum 10 years working experience in engineering construction as a QC Manager; 2;Proficient in English speaking and writing | {'Min': '10', 'Max': '16'} | {'Name': 'Branch of China Railway 18th Bureau Group Co Ltd', 'Id': '192341'} | 190722000003 | https://www.naukrigulf.com/project-manager-constructio-jobs-in-al-madina-al-munawarah-saudi-arabia-in-branch-of-china-railway-18th-bureau-group-co-ltd-10-to-16-years-n-cd-192341-jid-190722000003 | 1658175153 | 1 | false | false | false | false | false |  |  | false | false |  | QC Manager With Underpass Construction Project Experience |  | false | false | False | False | False | False | False |